# When I try to build apk in Android Studio I am getting an error

Tags: java, android, gradle

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Muslim\AndroidStudioProjects\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Muslim.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-25.2.0.aar\3a2c2c796890017fe46a33f67e87a476\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.class]))

Below is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main{
        jni.srcDirs=[]
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') {exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: Why are you compiling jars instead of adding gradle dependencies?
And why are you using nine old androids which is deprecated?
Change those two things and it see if it helps.

Comment: how to add gradle dependencies ? can you help me out . i am new to this

Comment: You can read the official Android developer's site and use Google to figure out how to add gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Same error after Android 3.0 update.

After a "Clean project" everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

> Go to File-> Invalidate Cache and Restart.
>
> After Restart Build -> Build APK(s)

Also, you can change your gradle file using compile dependency from the web rather than libs folder.

```
complie 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
complie 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```